# Storing ETC in smart contract

Tags: contract-development, ether, ethereum-classic

Is there any possibility to write an Ethereum based smart contract which can store ETC along with ETH?

Answer (score 1):

As of today ETH and ETC are separate chains.
So there is no way to create a contract living only on one of the chains and be sure coins on the other will not be spent.

What is possible though is to create two contracts (code might be the same) that implement the algorithm known as "atomic swap" that would allow secure exchange of coins.